# Traefik and authelia not working properly

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I am new with authelia, traefik, and am using docker compose and try to configure these apps to run with a self signed certificated (for now).

So far I have this:

at docker-compose.yml

```
---
version: '3'

services:
traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    volumes:
      - /working_dir/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.tls.options=default'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=authelia@docker'
    command:
      - '--api'
      - '--log=true'
      - '--log.level=DEBUG'
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/certificates.yml'
      - '--entrypoints.http=true'
      - '--entrypoints.http.address=:80'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=https'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https'
      - '--entrypoints.https=true'
      - '--entrypoints.https.address=:443'
    ports:
      - 8080:80  # Web
      - 1443:443 # https    
authelia:
    image: authelia/authelia
    container_name: authelia
    volumes:
      - /working_dir/authelia:/config
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.rule=Host(`authelia.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.tls.options=default'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.address=http://authelia:9091/api/verify?rd=https://authelia.example.com'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=Remote-User,Remote-Groups,Remote-Name,Remote-Email'
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      ## In production the healthcheck section should be commented.
      disable: true

whoami:
  image: traefik/whoami
  container_name: whoami
  labels:
    - 'traefik.enable=true'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=https'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.options=default'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=authelia@docker'
```

ls -la /working_dir

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 me mygrp 4099 Nov 28 15:18 authelia
drwxr-xr-x.  2 me mygrp   54 Nov 29 11:33 traefik
```

ls -la /working_dir/traefik

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 me mygrp 115 Nov 25 11:22 certificates.yml
drwxrwxrwx. 2 me mygrp  87 Nov 25 11:37 certs
```

ls -la /working_dir/traefik/certs

```
-r--------. 1 me mygrp 1689 Nov 29 11:37 private.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 me mygrp 1387 Nov 29 11:37 public.crt
```

cat /working_dir/traefik/certificates.yml

```
---
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/traefik/certs/public.crt
      keyFile: /etc/traefik/certs/private.pem
```

cat /working_dir/authelia/configuration.yml

```
---
###############################################################
#                   Authelia configuration                    #
###############################################################

jwt_secret: "p*fsjdkfds7dsf7sdf/&65fdkjdfsjkfj"
default_redirection_url: https://whoami.example.com

server:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 9091

log:
  level: debug

totp:
  issuer: authelia.com

authentication_backend:
  file:
    path: /config/users_database.yml

access_control:
  default_policy: deny
  rules:
    - domain: whoami.example.com
      policy: one_factor
    - domain: traefik.example.com
      policy: one_factor

session:
  name: authelia_session
  secret: "d667677&&%%$45u3aYKaNVA3YD5677f66ff663yy"
  expiration: 3600  # 1 hour
  inactivity: 300  # 5 minutes
  domain: example.com  # Should match whatever your root protected domain is

regulation:
  max_retries: 3
  find_time: 120
  ban_time: 300

storage:
  encryption_key: "IF##344rr343WQ%pQ#q5KpkGX!QMcYJab$M2h3344343"
  local:
    path: /config/db.sqlite3

notifier:
  filesystem:
    filename: /config/notification.txt
```

cat  /working_dir/authelia/users_database.yml

```
---
###############################################################
#                         Users Database                      #
###############################################################

# This file can be used if you do not have an LDAP set up.

# List of users
users:
  authelia:
    disabled: false
    displayname: "Authelia User"
    password: "$6$rounds=50000$Bterte6466464WD8F2q$Zis.ixdg9s/UOJYrs56b5QEZFiZECu0qZVNsIYxBaNJ7ucIL.nlxVCT5tqh8KHG8X4tlwCFm344hth5qRFN/"  # yamllint disable-line rule:line-length
    email: authelia@authelia.com
    groups:
      - admins
      - dev
```

I did: `docker compose up -d`

All containers are up and running.

When I try to access https://whoami.example.com or https://traefik.example.com I get this message in the browser:

```
404 page not found
```

Any ideas?

I did found some errors in the log files:

docker compose logs traefik

```
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:47:49+01:00" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=http middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:47:49+01:00" level=debug msg="No store is defined to add the certificate MIID0TCCArmgAwIBAgIUIwFmQm72aSK0T0owWpF0Bnnt5tgwDQ, it will be added to the default store."
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:47:49+01:00" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) example.com"
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:47:49+01:00" level=debug msg="No default certificate, fallback to the internal generated certificate" tlsStoreName=default
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:47:49+01:00" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" entryPointName=http routerName=http-to-https@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
...
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:49:07+01:00" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"whoami.example.com\""
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:49:07+01:00" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 175.20.0.1:58796: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:49:11+01:00" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"whoami.example.com\""
traefik  | time="2023-11-30T16:58:19+01:00" level=warning msg="Error checking new version: Get \"https://update.traefik.io/repos/traefik/traefik/releases\": dial tcp 13.39.208.199:443: i/o timeout"
```